# Where would typecasting to boolean with `not not` instead of `bool()` fail?

Tags: python, boolean

To typecast a value to boolean, I usually do the following:

```
not not value
```

This is faster than using `bool`. Output from timeit:

```
python -m timeit '[bool(t) for t in [[], {}, "", 0, [1], {"a": "n"}, "asdf", 2323]]'    
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.81 usec per loop
python -m timeit '[(not not t) for t in [[], {}, "", 0, [1], {"a": "n"}, "asdf", 2323]]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 usec per loop
```

I tried to test it using this:

```
>>> [bool(t) == (not not t) for t in [None, [], {}, "", 0, [1], {'a': 'n'}, "asdf", 2323]]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

And it seems to work for most common cases.

Arguments on readability aside, where does this fail, or why would this be a bad thing to do?

Comment: You are pretty unlucky that bool() is the performance bottleneck of your app

Comment: A bit verbose: python -m timeit '[ (True if t else False) for t in [[], {}, "", 0, [1], {"a": "n"}, "asdf", 2323]]' How well this scores at your platform?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan lol. The question was more out of curiosity, rather than for "optimization"

Comment: Interesting, I can confirm these results on my machine. It probably has to do with function lookup.

Comment: @Kugel actually, it's the function call… Function calls in CPython are *very* slow: `%timeit bool and (not not 0)` is still faster than `bool(0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ignacio notes, both `bool()` and `not` invoke the same method (see [operator.not_](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.not_), [__nonzero__](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__),and the note there about `__len__`), so there's no need to compare them across different object types.

You'll get more accurate results if you test only the operator/function call (this is using ipython's `%timeit` magic method):

```
In [1]: %timeit not not 0
10000000 loops, best of 3: 60.2 ns per loop

In [2]: %timeit bool(1)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 180 ns per loop

In [3]: %timeit bool(0)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 177 ns per loop

In [4]: %timeit not not 1
10000000 loops, best of 3: 60.5 ns per loop
```

And Paulo's suggestion:

```
In [3]: %timeit True if 0 else False
10000000 loops, best of 3: 73 ns per loop

In [4]: %timeit True if 1 else False
10000000 loops, best of 3: 54.4 ns per loop
```

And one more, for funsies:

```
In [6]: %timeit 0 and True or False
10000000 loops, best of 3: 72.7 ns per loop

In [7]: %timeit 1 and True or False
10000000 loops, best of 3: 78.1 ns per loop
```

(all these tests were run against `Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53), [GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin`)

So, to answer your question "would [using not not] be a bad thing to do": yes, definitely. If you care about readability, `bool(…)` is clearer, and if you care about performance, `True if … else False` is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Both operations invoke the same method (`__nonzero__()` on 2.x, `__bool__()` on 3.x), so both would have the same failure modes.