# check existence of element in list

Tags: python

I have a list of `Person` objects and I'd like to check if a person exists based on their name. Is there an easier way to do so other than this loop?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name): 
        self.name = name


found = False

for p in person_list:
    if p.name == "Alan":
        found = True
        break
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of Person and the list?

Comment: Please use 4-space indentation

Comment: Can you share the objects' list?

Answer (score 5):

```py
any(p.name == "Alan" for p in person_list)
```

It returns you a `bool` literal - `True` or `False`

Answer (score 4):

You could try with `any`:

```
found = any(p.name == 'Alan' for p in person_list)
```

And printing `found` would give either `True` or `False`.

Or you could also do a list comprehension:

```
found = not not [p for p in person_list if p.name == 'Alan']
```

Comment: Using `any` is much better than a list comprehension, as `any` will return as soon as it finds a single `True` value in the iterable. But if you do want to use list comprehensions, surely `bool(<some_list>)` is much cleaner than `not not <some_list>`?

Comment: @AlexWaygood Performance wise `not not` is better, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264942/where-would-typecasting-to-boolean-with-not-not-instead-of-bool-fail

Comment: Well TIL something new — thanks! Though I much prefer the `True if <some_list> else False` option suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13265186/13990016

Answer (score -1):

You can first make a list of names and then use the count method:

```
list(map(lambda x: x.name, person_list)).count('Alan') > 0
```

It will return False if the person doesn't exist in the list.

I performed a speed test comparing `map` and `any` approach:

```
names = list(map(str, np.random.randint(0, 10, 1000)))

person_list = [Person(name) for name in names]

%timeit list(map(lambda x: x.name, person_list)).count('Alan') > 0

%timeit any(p.name == 'Alan' for p in person_list)
```

and the results:

```
207 µs ± 34.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
122 µs ± 17.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

So `any` approach is faster.

**UPDATE**

Using `attrgetter` with `map` reaches the best performance:

```
from operator import attrgetter
f = attrgetter('name')

names = list(map(str, np.random.randint(0, 10, 1000)))

person_list = [Person(name) for name in names]

%timeit list(map(f, person_list)).count('Alan') > 0

%timeit any(f(p) == 'Alan' for p in person_list)
```

And the result:

```
110 µs ± 18.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
172 µs ± 6.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: How does this solution filter the list of Persons based off the name of that person? Maybe OP doesn't have a person object to check with..

Comment: What is `person`... There is no such a thing

Comment: @siamaksafari It suppose to return True or Falsem, also I didn't downvote

Comment: @U12-Forward Now it returns True or False